# delete double on SQL with multiple primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL 2008 R2. I have 5 composite Primary keys

```
(NOID ,CODE_CLIENT,CODE_DEST,DATE_CLOTURE,DATE_CLOTUR_REEL)
```

on my table.

I try to delete the double with this syntax:

```
DELETE
FROM [LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL]
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT NOID ,
            CODE_CLIENT,
            CODE_DEST,
            DATE_CLOTURE,
            DATE_CLOTUR_REEL
     FROM LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL
     GROUP BY NOID ,
              CODE_CLIENT,
              CODE_DEST,
              DATE_CLOTURE,
              DATE_CLOTUR_REEL HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

it delete all the entry, fortunately I have made a backup.

Before I just had 4 composite Primary keys, and I add the last one DATE_CLOTUR_REEL. Because the value of primary keys can not be null then I put the value `getdate()` into this keys. Because of that I can not set all 5 as composite primary keys because I have double.
So now, there are no primary keys on my table.

Comment: This is why when doing things like this, you should use transactions so that you an roll them back if they don't do exactly what you want.

Comment: You don't have four primary keys. You may have a *single* primary key per table. You *might* have a composite primary key, composed of 4 (your text) or 5 (your example) columns.

Comment: But, if you *have* a declared primary key, duplicates shouldn't be possible anyway, so you need to be clear on exactly what your table setup is (maybe add a `CREATE TABLE` script to your question, deleting some irrelevant columns if needed), what the data currently looks like, and what you're attempting to do.

Comment: If you count primary keys they are 5 instead of 4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting duplicate form your table:

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NOID ,CODE_CLIENT,CODE_DEST,DATE_CLOTURE,DATE_CLOTUR_REEL
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
         FROM   LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that subquery in exists statement is not bound with "delete from" in any way. The result is that existence of ANY doubles delets ALL records in a table. Besides, I think you messed something up with primary keys (as commented by other users).
Anyway, you could use CTE to remove duplicates:

```
WITH CTE (COl1,Col2, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
    SELECT COl1,Col2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COl1,Col2 ORDER BY Col1) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM DuplicateRcordTable
)

DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
```